Unable show output in modelsim
I am making an 8-bit microcontroller in Verilog.  Here is my code for top level module and testbench:
module MicroController(clk, rst);
    input clk, rst;
    parameter LOAD = 2'b00,FETCH = 2'b01, DECODE = 2'b10, EXECUTE = 2'b11;
    reg [1:0] current_state, next_state;
    reg [11:0] instr_set [25:0];
    reg load_done;
    reg [7:0] load_addr;
    wire [11:0] load_instr;
    reg [7:0] PC, DR, Acc;  // Program Counter, Data Register, Accumulator
    reg [11:0] IR;          // Instruction Register
    reg [3:0] SR;           // Status Register
    wire PC_E, Acc_E, SR_E, DR_E, IR_E;             // Enable signals
    reg PC_clr, Acc_clr, SR_clr, DR_clr, IR_clr;    // Clear signals
    wire [7:0] PC_updated, DR_updated;
    wire [11:0] IR_updated;
    wire [3:0] SR_updated;
    wire PMem_E, DMem_E, DMem_WE, ALU_E, PMem_LE, MUX1_Sel, MUX2_Sel;
    wire [3:0] ALU_Mode;    // ALU Output Mode
    wire [7:0] Adder_Out;
    wire [7:0] ALU_Out, ALU_Oper2;
 
    // Load instructions into Program Memory
    initial begin
        $readmemb("C:/Users/Zero/Documents/Microcontroller/instr_set.dat", instr_set, 0, 25);
    end

    // Control logic
    ControlUnit Control_Unit(.stage(current_state),
                               .IR(IR),             // Instruction Register
                               .SR(SR),             // Status Register
                               .PC_E(PC_E),         // PC Enable
                               .Acc_E(Acc_E),       // Accumulator Enable
                               .SR_E(SR_E),         // SR Enable
                               .IR_E(IR_E),         // IR Enable
                               .DR_E(DR_E),         // DR Enable
                               .PMem_E(PMem_E),     // PMem Enable
                               .DMem_E(DMem_E),     // DMem Enable
                               .DMem_WE(DMem_WE),   // DMem Write Enable
                               .ALU_E(ALU_E),       // ALU Enable
                               .MUX1_Sel(MUX1_Sel), // MUX1 Selection line
                               .MUX2_Sel(MUX2_Sel), // MUX2 Selection line
                               .PMem_LE(PMem_LE),   // PMem Load Enable
                               .ALU_Mode(ALU_Mode));// ALU Output Mode

    // ALU
    ALU ALU_unit(.Operand1(Acc),
                 .Operand2(ALU_Oper2),
                 .E(ALU_E),
                 .Mode(ALU_Mode),
                 .CFlags(SR),                   // Current Flags  
                 .Out(ALU_Out),
                 .Flags(SR_updated));           // Updated Flags
                 /* 4 Flag bits are Z (zero),
                    C (carry), S (sign), O (overflow) 
                    in order from MSB to LSB */

    // PC Adder
    Adder PC_Adder(.In(PC),
                   .Out(Adder_Out));

    // MUX1
    MUX MUX1_unit(.In1(Adder_Out),
                  .In2(IR[7:0]),
                  .Sel(MUX1_Sel),
                  .Out(PC_updated));

    // MUX2
    MUX MUX2_unit(.In1(DR),
                  .In2(IR[7:0]),
                  .Sel(MUX2_Sel),
                  .Out(ALU_Oper2));

    // Program Memory
    PMem PMem_unit(.clk(clk),
                   .E(PMem_E), 
                   .Addr(PC),           // Address port
                   .I(IR_updated),      // Next instruction
                   // 3 special ports, used to load program to the memory
                   .LE(PMem_LE),        // Load enable port 
                   .LA(load_addr),      // Load address port
                   .LI(load_instr));    // Load instruction port

    // Data Memory
    DMem DMem_unit(.clk(clk),
                   .E(DMem_E),
                   .WE(DMem_WE),        // Write enable port
                   .Addr(IR[3:0]),      // Address port 
                   .DI(ALU_Out),        // Data input port
                   .DO(DR_updated));    // Data output port

    // LOAD
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if(rst == 1) begin
            load_addr <= 0;
            load_done <= 1'b0;
        end 
        else if(PMem_LE == 1) begin 
            load_addr <= load_addr + 8'd1;
            if(load_addr == 8'd25) begin     // All instructions loaded
                load_addr <= 8'd0;          // into Program Memory
                load_done <= 1'b1;
            end
            else begin
                load_done <= 1'b0;
            end
        end 
    end

    assign load_instr = instr_set[load_addr];
    
    // Changing the Current State
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if(rst == 1)
            current_state <= LOAD;
        else
            current_state <= next_state;
    end

    // State Transitions
    always @(*) begin
        PC_clr = 0;
        Acc_clr = 0;
        SR_clr = 0;
        DR_clr = 0; 
        IR_clr = 0;
        case(current_state)
            LOAD: begin
                if(load_done == 1) begin
                    next_state = FETCH;   // LOAD -> FETCH
                    PC_clr = 1;           // Set Clear to 1 for all registers
                    Acc_clr = 1;
                    SR_clr = 1;
                    DR_clr = 1; 
                    IR_clr = 1;
                end
                else
                    next_state = LOAD;
            end
            FETCH: next_state = DECODE;     // FETCH -> DECODE
            
            DECODE: next_state = EXECUTE;   // DECODE -> EXECUTE
            
            EXECUTE: next_state = FETCH;    // EXECUTE -> FETCH
        endcase
    end

    // Assigning Program Counter, Accumulator, Status Register
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if(rst == 1) begin
            PC <= 8'd0;             // Clear all registers
            Acc <= 8'd0;
            SR <= 4'd0;
        end
        else begin
            if(PC_E == 1'd1) 
                PC <= PC_updated;   // Update Program Counter
            else if (PC_clr == 1)     
                PC <= 8'd0;         // Clear Program Counter
            if(Acc_E == 1'd1) 
                Acc <= ALU_Out;     // Update Accumulator
            else if (Acc_clr == 1)    
                Acc <= 8'd0;        // Clear Accumulator
            if(SR_E == 1'd1) 
                SR <= SR_updated;   // Update Status Register
            else if (SR_clr == 1)     
                SR <= 4'd0;         // Clear Status Register
        end
    end

    // Assigning Data Register, Instruction Register
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if(DR_E == 1'd1) 
            DR <= DR_updated;   // Update Data Register
        else if (DR_clr == 1)     
            DR  <= 8'd0;        // Clear Data Register
        if(IR_E == 1'd1) 
            IR <= IR_updated;   // Next Instruction
        else if(IR_clr == 1)      
            IR <= 12'd0;        // Clear Instruction Register
    end

endmodule


`timescale 1ns/10ps

module MicroController_tb;

    // Inputs
    reg clk;        // Positive edge triggered clock
    reg rst;        // Active high reset

    // Internal signals from the DUT (Device Under Test)
    wire [7:0] DI;      // Data Input to DMem
    wire E;             // ALU Enable
    wire [7:0] ALU_Out; // ALU Output
    wire [7:0] Acc;     // Accumulator
    wire [3:0] SR;      // Status Register

    // Instantiate MicroController module (DUT)
    MicroController UUT(
        .clk(clk),
        .rst(rst)
    );

    // Clock generation (positive edge triggered)
    always #5 clk = ~clk;

    // Dump all signals to a .vcd file for visualization in ModelSim
    initial begin
        $dumpfile("MicroController_tb.vcd");  // Specify the VCD file
        $dumpvars(0, MicroController_tb);     // Dump all variables in this module

        // Initialize signals
        clk = 0;        
        rst = 1;  // Activate reset
        
        #20 rst = 0;  // Deactivate reset after 20 ns
        
        // Run the simulation for 1000 ns
        #980 $finish;
    end

    // Monitor the values of specific signals during the simulation
    initial begin
        $monitor(
            "Time=%0t | rst=%b | clk=%b | DI=%h | E=%b | ALU_Out=%h | Acc=%h | SR=%b", 
            $time, rst, clk, DI, E, ALU_Out, Acc, SR
        );
    end

endmodule

Here is my instr_set.dat file contents:
000000000000
101100000101
001000100000
101100001100
001000100001
101100000010
001000100010
001101110001
011000010000
001100110001
001101110000
011000001110
001100110000
000100010110
001100110001
000100010110
001100110010
001101110000
011000010101
001100110000
000100010110
001100110010
001000100011
000100010111

but when i try to see the output of testbench in modelsim i get nothing, here is the result:
my modelsim output
i am sure that the file is being read based on this displayed in modelsim:
** Warning: (vsim-PLI-3408) Too few data words read on line 24 of file "C:/Users/Zero/Documents/Microcontroller/instr_set.dat". Expected 26, found 24.    : C:/Users/Zero/Documents/Microcontroller/MicroController.v(24)

(i fixed the warning still no luck)
Here is what i want to display in modelsim:
expected modelsim output

I figured it out, the testbench code was wrong, i wasn't assigning anything after updating the code it fixed. Here is the updated code, you can see the difference for anyone who faces the same problem:
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module MicroController_tb;

    // Inputs
    reg clk;
    reg rst;
    reg PMem_LE;

    // Outputs
    wire [7:0] DI;           // Data Input to DMem
    wire [7:0] ALU_Out;      // ALU Output
    wire [7:0] Acc;          // Accumulator
    wire [3:0] SR;           // Status Register
    wire [11:0] instr_set;   // Instruction set

    // Internal signals
    wire E;                  // ALU Enable

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    MicroController uut (
        .clk(clk),
        .rst(rst)
    );

    assign DI = uut.DR_updated;      // Monitor Data Register update
    assign E = uut.ALU_E;           // ALU Enable signal
    assign ALU_Out = uut.ALU_Out;   // ALU Output
    assign Acc = uut.Acc;           // Accumulator
    assign SR = uut.SR;             // Status Register
    assign instr_set = uut.instr_set[0]; // Instruction set, observing the first instruction for simplicity

    // Clock generation
    initial begin
        clk = 0;
        forever #5 clk = ~clk; // 100 MHz clock frequency
    end

    // Testbench stimulus
    initial begin
        // Initialize inputs
        rst = 1;
        PMem_LE = 0;

        // Wait for the clock to stabilize
        #10;

        // De-assert reset
        rst = 0;

        // Load instructions into Program Memory
        PMem_LE = 1;
        #200;  // Allow time for all instructions to load
        PMem_LE = 0;

        // Run the microcontroller
        #500;

        // Assert reset again
        rst = 1;
        #20;

        // Finish simulation
        $stop;
    end

    // Monitor signals
    initial begin
        $dumpfile("MicroController_tb.vcd");
        $dumpvars(0, MicroController_tb);

        // Display signal values for debugging
        $monitor("Time: %0dns | DI: %h | E: %b | ALU_Out: %h | Acc: %h | SR: %b | instr_set: %h", 
                 $time, DI, E, ALU_Out, Acc, SR, instr_set);
    end

endmodule

